# Can't execute inner function strlen

Tags: c++

My task was to find length of C-styled string using function. I did solve the issue but when i passed my code through debugger I've found some strange thing. When the function finished it's job and returned me a number, on the moment of going to cout <<"***" << endl; before printing text on screen it is getting sent to function and function works again but using text which has to be printed on screen. And only after this it goes printed on screen. How does it work?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned strlen(const char *str)
{
    unsigned x = 0;
    while (str[x] != 0) x++;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    // Test 1
    const char* str1 = "How do you do";
    if (strlen(str1) == 13)
        cout << "Test 1 passed" << endl;
    else cout << "Test 1 failed" << endl;
    // Test 2
    const char* str2 = "";
    if (strlen(str2) == 0)
        std::cout << "Test 2 passed" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Test 2 failed" << std::endl;
    // Test 3
    const char* str3 = "This is stepik.org";
    if (strlen(str3) == 18)
        std::cout << "Test 3 passed" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Test 3 failed" << std::endl;
    const char* str4 = "Russian Federation";
    if (strlen(str4) == 18)
        std::cout << "Test 4 passed" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Test 4 failed" << std::endl;
    const char* str5 = "Russia";
    if (strlen(str5) == 6)
        std::cout << "Test 5 passed" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Test 5 failed" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking exactly. It sounds like you stepped into `operator<<` and are confused by what you found there. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it is actually quite clear - OP is seeing `cout` calling his version of `strlen`.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, I see it now. Though I'm still not sure the question is clear. I wouldn't have guessed that was the question without your explanation. But I'm glad someone was able to understand and answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You did a **BAD THING** - you have used a name from Standard Library (`strlen`) as the name of your own function. Effectively you have overridden it, and opened yourself up for all troubles. This program is ill-formed.

As a practical matter, `cout` with `char*` as an argument is going to determine the length of the string, calling `strlen`, which happens to be your function.